# One jQuery animation stopping another animation

Tags: jquery, animation, mouseenter, mouseleave

EDIT - SOLVED. Solution at the bottom.

I've been banging my head against a brick wall with this problem all afternoon. Not a genius with jQuery, so apols if there is already an answer for this - I'm not sure what to be sesarching for, and I've spent time searching!

I am trying to run two animations on one page. The first is a mousenter, mouseleave function that gives a fourway sliding door effect:

```
$('.qitem').each(function () {

        //grab the anchor and image path
        url = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
        img = $(this).find('img').attr('src');

        //remove the image
        $('img', this).remove();

        //append four corners/divs into it
        $(this).append('<div class="topLeft"></div><div class="topRight"></div><div class="bottomLeft"></div><div class="bottomRight"></div>');

        //set the background image to all the corners
        $(this).children('div').css('background-image','url('+ img + ')');

        $(this).find('div.topLeft').css({top:0, left:0, width:pos , height:posHeight});   
        $(this).find('div.topRight').css({top:0, left:pos, width:pos , height:posHeight});    
        $(this).find('div.bottomLeft').css({bottom:0, left:0, width:pos , height:posHeight}); 
        $(this).find('div.bottomRight').css({bottom:0, left:pos, width:pos , height:posHeight}); 

    }).mouseenter(function () {

        //animate the position

        $(this).find('div.topLeft').stop(false,true).animate({top:negHeight, left:neg}, {duration:speed_out, easing:style_out}); 
        $(this).find('div.topRight').stop(false,true).animate({top:negHeight, left:outHeight}, {duration:speed_out, easing:style_out});    
        $(this).find('div.bottomLeft').stop(false,true).animate({bottom:negHeight, left:neg}, {duration:speed_out, easing:style_out});   
        $(this).find('div.bottomRight').stop(false,true).animate({bottom:negHeight, left:outHeight}, {duration:speed_out, easing:style_out}); 

    }).mouseleave(function () {

        //put corners back to the original position
        $(this).find('div.topLeft').stop(false,true).animate({top:0, left:0}, {duration:speed_in, easing:style_in});   
        $(this).find('div.topRight').stop(false,true).animate({top:0, left:pos}, {duration:speed_in, easing:style_in});    
        $(this).find('div.bottomLeft').stop(false,true).animate({bottom:0, left:0}, {duration:speed_in, easing:style_in}); 
        $(this).find('div.bottomRight').stop(false,true).animate({bottom:0, left:pos}, {duration:speed_in, easing:style_in});  



    }).click (function () {

        //go to the url
        window.location = $(this).find('a').attr('href');   
    });
```

The second is a firefly effect, the pertinent animation code being here:

```
$.firefly.fly = function(sp) {

  $(sp).animate({
      top: $.firefly.random(($(window).height()-150)),  //offsets
      left: $.firefly.random(($(window).width()-150))
  }, (($.firefly.random(10) + 5) * 1000),function(){  $.firefly.fly(sp) } );

};
```

They both work perfectly on their own. However, when I combine them, it gets a bit weird. It seems to me that the firefly works by having 40 simultaneous animations for each firefly image, and assigns a random direction to each, and the same random duration to all the 'fireflies'.

Now, when I mouseenter the first jQuery script, it 'door' opens fine, the animation works. If the mouse stays hovering over the 'qitem' element, then it seems that when the firefly animation finishes its current iteration, the mouseleave event is called.

How can the second animation affect the first like this? I'm thinking that maybe there is some sort of 'reset' in the DOM, and the mouse pointer has to be detected again, so it appears that the mouse is 'leaving'.

I hope I've explained this well - please ask for any further clarification if it seems a bit muddled.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

EDIT - SOLVED

Ok, got it!

As usual, these things are always very simple. When you know how! It was reading every jQuery mouseleave/mouseenter thread I could find on stackoverflow that led me to the solution - z-index.

The 'fireflies' as they moved where hovering over the element linked to the mouseleave event, so triggering it. All I've had to do to fix is make sure that the mouseleave div has a higer z-index than the fireflies. Simple :-)